# pdfFiler in flutter (like chrome) / alternative of PsPDF

Tags: flutter, pdf, form-fields

I want to edit/fill the form field shown in pdf using flutter in the mobile app.

> Here you can see Chrome extension provide that feature on web i want
> same in a flutter : [pdfFiler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-editor-for-chromeedit/gphandlahdpffmccakmbngmbjnjiiahp)

psPDF package provides the same features but it's paid so i want an alternative of it. [psPDF](https://pub.dev/packages/pspdfkit_flutter)

example of webextesion : https://youtu.be/Pigq8EuZbdU

[image]